# Meteor: Limiting DDP Connections with ddp-rate-limiter package

Tags: javascript, security, meteor, ddp

I am trying to prevent a user to be able to call a Meteor method too often with the Meteor package `ddp-rate-limiter` (For example to prevent spamming or a DOS attack), but I can not get it to work.

Does anybody have an idea?

server/ddpRateLimiter.js:

```html
Meteor.methods({
  dosAttack: function() {console.log("dos");}
});

var preventDosAttack= {
  userId: function() {return true;},
  type: 'method',
  method: 'dosAttack'
}

DDPRateLimiter.addRule(preventDosAttack, 5, 1000);
```

With this code I can still run the method from the client console as often as I want to. (Tested with a for loop 100 times)

You can find the entire sourcecode here: [opensource project](http://github.com/minden/gotit)

And this certain commit here: [commit](https://github.com/minden/GotIt/tree/667319d9da1be2dbb9450afc5a0a137f86767ceb)

Thank you very much for your help,

Max

Comment: You are limiting it to 5 calls every 1000 ms. Are you sure you are making more calls than that? Also, maybe try adding it into Meteor.startup.

Comment: As a test I do 100 calls of the method dosAttack from the client console in a for loop and it will still print 100 times "dos" to the server console even if I put it into Meteor.startup.

Comment: FYI: rate limiting is now [built-in to Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddpratelimiter)

Comment: @MichelFloyd yes, I know. This is exactly what I am trying to figure out - how to use this new build in rate limiting functionality.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake is simple: It is not `'method': 'dosAttack'` but `'name': 'dosAttack'`. Seems like the example in the documentation [MeteorDoc DDPRateLimiter](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddpratelimiter) does the same mistake. I created an [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5728) on the meteor GitHub page

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiting is now offered as a vendor-supported Meteor package. I've recently used it to create [Meteor Candy](http://meteorcandy.com), the admin panel for Meteor. Here's how I did it.

First, add the package:

`meteor add ddp-rate-limiter`.

Second, define the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    myFancyMethod: function () {
        return true;
    }
})
```

Finally, define the rate limiting rules for it:

```
import { DDPRateLimiter } from 'meteor/ddp-rate-limiter';

var requestLimit = 5;
var requestTimeout = 5000;

DDPRateLimiter.addRule({
    type: "method",
    name: "myFancyMethod",
}, requestLimit, requestTimeout);
```