# Meteor Pub/Sub configure speed

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Is there a way to control the throughput (or the speed) of a Pub/Sub?

I have a meteor app and I want to control the throughput of an specific pub/sub for testing purposes inside my app

By the way, I use SubsManager for subscriptions

Thank you

Comment: Crudely put, why not put timeouts on inside the publisher?

Comment: Yes, it is a possible solution, so, you mean that there is no built-in way to do this throughput control, isn't it ?

Comment: See if these can give you some ideas : [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407113/throttling-method-calls-to-m-requests-in-n-seconds), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959184/how-can-you-throttle-calls-server-side), [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959984/meteor-limiting-ddp-connections-with-ddp-rate-limiter-package), [Four](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rate-limiting-methods)